# Get XML and transform to another xml format with context changes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Can you please help me to convert an xml to another format using xslt? I have an input XML which needs to be converted to another format, however I tried using XSLT, but in vain. Please provide me with a sample code.

Here is the source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
      <STEP-ProductInformation ExportTime="2017-11-03 14:45:02" ExportContext="en-EN" ContextID="en-EN" WorkspaceID="Main" UseContextLocale="false">
         <Products>
            <Product ID="prd_388061006" UserTypeID="obj_product" ParentID="prd_en_10000201">
               <Name>name</Name>
               <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="cls_1_6434100" Type="ref_product_to_erpgroup"/>
               <AssetCrossReference AssetID="173994" Type="ref_primary_product_image"/>
               <Values>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_010_KRL">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_010_KRL">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_011_KRS">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_011_KRS">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_nr">388061006</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_012_TVR">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_012_TVR">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_013_ELS">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_013_ELS">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_014_PSK">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_015_ODN">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_014_PSK">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_002_KLM">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_003_VLD">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_002_KLM">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_003_VLD">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_ar_nr">388061</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_004_RYA">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_004_RYA">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_005_YAR">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_006_TUL">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_005_YAR">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_006_TUL">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_001_SCH">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_001_SCH">2017-06-12</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_015_ODN">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_pt_brand" ID="184985">1977</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_max_until">31-dec-9999</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_pt_calc" Derived="true">name 1</Value>
               </Values>

            </Product>
            <Product ID="prd_15004" UserTypeID="obj_product" ParentID="prd_en_10005897">
               <Name>banana</Name>
               <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="cls_loy_bonus_current_5002_klm" Type="ref_loyalty_promotion"/>
               <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="cls_1_7361100" Type="ref_product_to_erpgroup"/>
               <AssetCrossReference AssetID="128178" Type="ref_primary_product_image"/>
               <Values>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_010_KRL">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_010_KRL">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_011_KRS">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_011_KRS">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_nr">15004</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_012_TVR">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_012_TVR">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_013_ELS">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_loy_current_promo_number">42010</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_013_ELS">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_014_PSK">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_015_ODN">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_014_PSK">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_002_KLM">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_003_VLD">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_002_KLM">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_003_VLD">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_ar_nr">15</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_004_RYA">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_004_RYA">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_005_YAR">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_006_TUL">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_005_YAR">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_loy_current_promo_name">extra bonuses</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_loy_current_promo_end_date">2017-10-24</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_loy_current_promo_start_date">2017-10-11</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_006_TUL">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_001_SCH">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_001_SCH">2017-08-08</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_015_ODN">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_max_until">31-dec-9999</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_pt_calc" Derived="true">name 2</Value>
               </Values>

            </Product>
            <Product ID="prd_1569001" UserTypeID="obj_product" ParentID="prd_en_10005921">
               <Name>name</Name>
               <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="cls_loy_bonus_current_5002_klm" Type="ref_loyalty_promotion"/>
               <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="cls_1_7361200" Type="ref_product_to_erpgroup"/>
               <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="cls_1_7361700" Type="ref_product_to_erpgroup"/>
               <AssetCrossReference AssetID="161621" Type="ref_primary_product_image"/>
               <AssetCrossReference AssetID="188035" Type="ref_secondary_image"/>
               <Values>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_010_KRL">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_010_KRL">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_011_KRS">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_011_KRS">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_nr">1569001</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_012_TVR">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_012_TVR">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_013_ELS">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_loy_current_promo_number">42010</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_013_ELS">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_014_PSK">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_015_ODN">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_014_PSK">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_002_KLM">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_003_VLD">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_002_KLM">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_003_VLD">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_ar_nr">1569</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_004_RYA">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_004_RYA">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_005_YAR">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_006_TUL">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_005_YAR">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_loy_current_promo_name">extra bonuses</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_loy_current_promo_end_date">2017-10-24</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_loy_current_promo_start_date">2017-10-11</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_006_TUL">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_001_SCH">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_sd_001_SCH">2017-04-05</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_ed_015_ODN">9999-12-31</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_max_until">31-dec-9999</Value>
                  <Value AttributeID="atr_pt_calc" Derived="true">name 3</Value>
               </Values>

            </Product>
         </Products>
      </STEP-ProductInformation>
   </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

and output is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <Message1>
      <Id>SAP_ERP_MATNR</Id>
      <Timestamp/>
      <UserName/>
      <SourceSystemId/>
      <Products>
         <IdOrigin>SAP_ERP_MATNR</IdOrigin>
         <Id>388061</Id>
         <Name>name 1</Name>
         <Description>name 1</Description>
      </Products>
      <Products>
         <IdOrigin>SAP_ERP_MATNR</IdOrigin>
         <Id>388061</Id>
         <Name>name 1</Name>
         <Description>name 1</Description>
      </Products>
      <Products>
         <IdOrigin>SAP_ERP_MATNR</IdOrigin>
         <Id>388061</Id>
         <Name>name 1</Name>
         <Description>name 1</Description>
      </Products>
   </Message1>
   <Message2/>
   <Message3/>
</Messages>
```

after XSL transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:StringBuffer="java.lang.StringBuffer" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge"  exclude-result-prefixes="java date StringBuffer" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:variable name="valueFromSource" select=".//Product"/>
<Messages>
    <Message1>
    <Id>SAP_ERP_MATNR</Id>
    <Timestamp></Timestamp>
    <UserName></UserName>
    <SourceSystemId></SourceSystemId>
    <xsl:for-each select="$valueFromSource">
    <Products>
        <IdOrigin>SAP_ERP_MATNR</IdOrigin>
        <Id><xsl:value-of select="..//Value[@AttributeID='atr_ext_ar_nr']"/></Id>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="/ns0:Messages/ns0:Message1/STEP-ProductInformation/Products/Product/Values/Value[@AttributeID='atr_pt_calc']"/></Name>
        <Description><xsl:value-of select="/ns0:Messages/ns0:Message1/STEP-ProductInformation/Products/Product/Values/Value[@AttributeID='atr_pt_calc']"/></Description>
    </Products>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Message1>
    <Message2>

    </Message2>
    <Message3>

    </Message3>
</Messages>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but i want to get that output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <Message1>
      <Id>SAP_ERP_MATNR</Id>
      <Timestamp/>
      <UserName/>
      <SourceSystemId/>
      <Products>
         <IdOrigin>SAP_ERP_MATNR</IdOrigin>
         <Id>388061</Id>
         <Name>name 1</Name>
         <Description>name 1</Description>
      </Products>
      <Products>
         <IdOrigin>SAP_ERP_MATNR</IdOrigin>
         <Id>15</Id>
         <Name>name 2</Name>
         <Description>name 2</Description>
      </Products>
      <Products>
         <IdOrigin>SAP_ERP_MATNR</IdOrigin>
         <Id>1569</Id>
         <Name>name 3</Name>
         <Description>name 3</Description>
      </Products>
   </Message1>
   <Message2/>
   <Message3/>
</Messages>
```

name 2 instead name 1, name 3 instead name 1.
15 instead 388061, 1569 instead 388061.

What i should change in my XSL to get the correct result?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of your expressions in the `xsl:value-of` start with `/ns0:Messages/` which means they will start selecting from the document node, which will end up selecting the first value it finds in the document regardless of where you are positioned.

Change the `xsl:for-each` to this, which has the expressions relative to the current `Product` node.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$valueFromSource">
    <Products>
        <IdOrigin>SAP_ERP_MATNR</IdOrigin>
        <Id><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value[@AttributeID='atr_ext_ar_nr']"/></Id>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value[@AttributeID='atr_pt_calc']"/></Name>
        <Description><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value[@AttributeID='atr_pt_calc']"/></Description>
    </Products>
</xsl:for-each>
```